# Angular, rendering html on the first item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat in my page for rendering all my blog posts, which is working fine. What i'd like to have is that on the first iteration in the repeat to also render some random text that will be next to the first of my posts. As it currently stands the random text is rendered next to all the posts. Is there a way to render it only on the first one?

```
   <div ng-repeat="post in blogs | orderBy:post.timestamp:true">
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4 col-xs-12'>
          <h4> Welcome to my blog </h4>
          <p> Some random text here </p>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-8 col-xs-0'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-0">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 post-{{post.id}} blog-posts-teaser" ng-class="{'lastBlogPost': $last}">
          <h4><a ng-href="#/blog/{{returnBlogUrl(post.title)}}" class='blog-title'>{{post.title}}</a></h4>
          <p>{{post.content | wordLimit:true:200:'...'}}</p>
          <p><a class='read-more' ng-href="#/blog/{{returnBlogUrl(post.title)}}" >Read more &#8594;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$first` the same way that you're using `$last`.

```
<p ng-if='$first'> Some random text here </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$first` inside the `ng-repeat`-ed block. This variable is set to true in case of the first item of the collection.

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> `$first` - `boolean`  - true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.